# Error 403 al acceder a virtualhost apache

Tags: linux, apache, apache2

Esta es mi configuración del virtualhost:

```
<Macro VHost $PORT $SERVERADMIN $SERVERNAME $SERVERALIAS $DOCUMENTROOT $PASS $LOG_DIR>
    <VirtualHost *:$PORT>
        ServerAdmin $SERVERADMIN

            ServerName $SERVERNAME
            ServerAlias $SERVERALIAS

            DocumentRoot $DOCUMENTROOT
            <Directory $DOCUMENTROOT>
                Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
                AllowOverride All
                Order deny,allow
                Allow from all
            </Directory>

            ErrorLog "$LOG_DIR/error.log"

            LogLevel warn

            CustomLog "$LOG_DIR/access.log" common
        </VirtualHost>
</Macro>
```

Answer (score 1):

La solución era bastante simple me hacia falta agregar esta directiva:

```
Require all granted

<Directory $DOCUMENTROOT>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```